# How to create dictionary from a grouped elements?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with elements that I wanted to group by the value of a property. Later I would like to create a dictionary which key is this value that I used to group and the value a list (or IEnumerable) of the elements that are each group.

I am trying something like that:

```
Dictionary<long, Ienumerable<MyType>> dic = lstWithElements.GroupBy(x=>x.ID).ToDictionary(x=>x.????)
```

But in the `ToDictionary` method I don't have the ID property. So, how could I create my dictionary with the grouped items?

Comment: Can u include your input structure and output you are expecting?

Comment: No, x.Key does not work, as ToDictionary would provide Dictionary<long, IGrouping<MyType>> instead Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MyType>>.
Please look on my answer down there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) method has a couple of overloads, but since your `Dictionary` uses an `IEnumerable<MyType>` for its `Value`, you're probably interested in the [overload that accepts two parameters: a key selector, and an element selector.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MyType>> dic = lstWithElements.GroupBy(x=>x.ID).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x => x.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: UNFAIR, I made a coffee break between writing answer and you created right answer in mean time:)

Answer (score 5):

The overload of `GroupBy` [that you're using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, MyType>>`. [`IGrouping<long, MyType>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provides a `Key` property of type `long`, representing the projected value by which elements were grouped, and also implements `IEnumerable<MyType>`.

So essentially, what you need is:

```
var dic = lstWithElements.GroupBy(x => x.ID).ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```

Note: As pointed out in comments, this produces an `IDictionary<long, IGrouping<long, MyType>>`. This isn't really a problem, as long as you're only *retrieving* elements from the dictionary, and not trying to add new `IEnumerable<MyType>`s later on (which seems unlikely). If you do need precisely an `IDictionary<long, IEnumerable<long, MyType>>`, use the code outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998151/1726343).

Comment: This shares the same issue as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998068/1187982), which is that the values in the dictionary are an `IGrouping<long, MyType>` rather than `IEnumerable<MyType>`.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Yes, and there is no problem with this. The least specific interface implementation should be dictated by consuming code, not baked into local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I hadn't considered this.  Enjoy your upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<long, IGrouping<long,MyType>> dic = lstWithElements.GroupBy(x=>x.ID).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key)
```

Comment: This is a bit redundant, as attempting to access the values of any key in the dictionary gives you an `IGrouping<long, MyType>`, instead of an `IEnumerable<MyType>`, and you can access elements of `IGrouping` via their key.  It just feels really clumsy.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer An `IGrouping<long, MyType>` *is* an `IEnumerable<MyType>`. Any consuming code that expects an `IEnumerable<T2>` will happily accept an `IGrouping<T1, T2>`. There's nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin What if you're expecting a `Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MyType>>`?

Comment: @juharr The use case here doesn't seem like the OP will be using the dictionary contravariantly, i.e. to add elements. They're likely doing this for quick access.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer There is one case,where it won't work Joshua.
If you have to assign your result from ToDictionary to expected dictionary:

Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<MyType>> dictionary =
lstWithElements
.GroupBy(x=>x.ID)
.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key);

it won't let you do that. it is completely different generic type and conversion error will occur.

Yes, if an interface consumes IEnumerable<T>
then it will consume IGrouping<TKey, T> as well,
but same does not apply for Dictionary,as
Dictionary<TKey, IGrouping<TKey, T>>
does not inherit from
Dictionary<TKey, IENumerable<T>>,that is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I presume, that your data structure is at minimum this:

```
class MyType //or struct
{
   long ID;
};
```

You want a list:

```
List<MyType> list;//with instances of MyType
```

either with different instances of MyType and same ID(**making ID non-unique, is not best design perhaps**) or some instances are in the list multiple times, what seems to be a better case, but either will work for question asked.

Now, GroupBy, what it does? List

```
List<MyType>
```

is transformed to

```
IEnumerable<MyType>
```

then GroupBy(x => x.ID) is grouping and providing:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, MyType>>
```

so we get elements of

```
IGrouping<long, MyType>
```

Now IGrouping knows everything IEnumerable does, interface inheritance, plus it has Key. So if you want your expected dictionary type:

```
Dictionary<long,IEnumerable<MyType>>
```

you have to do this:

```
var dictionary =
list
.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.AsEnumerable())
;
```

ToDictionary allows to chose the Key from elements and also allows to transform Value stored for given key, so we can use this approach and call

```
x.AsEnumerable()
```

as IGrouping is inherited from IEnumerable.

Hope this longer explanation helps :).